# Why is the angle a well-defined quantity in a Euclidean space?

Tags: linear-algebra, inner-products

I am having a problem with an exercise. In a certain euclidean space, the angle between two vectors $u$ and $v$ is said to be $\theta$ which satisfies the equation:

$$\cos\theta=\frac{(u,v)}{\|u\|\|v\|}$$

Why is the angle a well-defined quantity if $\theta \in [0;\pi]$?

Comment: It isn't, unless you also add the condition $0\le\theta\le\pi$.

Comment: Yes we have this condition

Comment: @user43758: What does the graph of $\cos$ look like?

Comment: If theta is between 0 and pi, cos is a decreasing function

Comment: Can someone help me?

Comment: You also need $\: u\neq \mathbf{0} \:$ and $\: v\neq \mathbf{0} \:$. $\;\;$

Comment: user43758, I think this is a great question. Why did you flag your own question as "not a real question"?

Comment: Because I saw it somewhere else but I lost the link

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It's not.

But suppose you add the restriction that $\|u\| >0, \|v\|>0$. By the [Cauchy-Schwarz inequality](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Cauchy%E2%80%93Schwarz_inequality), $|(u,v)| \leq \|u\|\|v\|$, so
$$-1 \leq \frac{(u,v)}{\|u\|\|v\|} \leq 1.$$

It follows that $\theta\in [0,\pi]$ exists and is unique, since $\cos$ is a bijection from $[0,\pi]$ to $[-1,1]$.

$\hspace{3cm}$[image: cos(x) is a bijection]

Comment: theta is between 0 and $\pi$

Comment: Yes. Are you still confused about a part of the answer?

Comment: Yes. In the question they already told be the interval between which theta is defined. 
Then they are asking me why is the angle a well defined quantity?

Comment: @user43758: It's well-defined because $\cos:[0,\pi]\to[-1,1]$ is a bijection (as stated in this answer).

Comment: @user7530: I hope I didn't modify too much.

Comment: @robjohn Awesome! Thanks!